# Selectively push in viewWillAppear in a UIViewControllerContainer

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

We have an app where a model object can pass through various states in a progressive fashion - think of an `Order` progressing to sale, for example. Each state of the `Order` is handled by a different view controller.

Each view controller recognizes what state(s) it can handle, and when a state has been reached that it cannot handle, pushes the subsequent view controller to handle the next state. Various events can cause a VC to update its view; a method `setupViewByOrderState` is called at this point. The same method is called in `viewDidAppear`.

For example, say an `Order` can pass through states 1-10. ViewController A handles states 1-2, B handles 3-5, and C handles 6-10.

If A is handed an order in state 1 or 2, it configures itself. If it is handed an order in state 3 or greater, it pushes a B, and hands off the order. Etc.

One advantage of this technique is that the first VC is an 'entry point' - hand it a given `Order` and it will push all the necessary VCs until one is reached that can handle the `Order` in its current state, without logic explicitly coding state->VC correspondences ever needing to exist outside each VC.

A problem arises, though, should one wish to pop backward through a view stack or dismiss modals. As soon as C popped, the `viewDidAppear` of B is called, which immediately puts it back on (to handle the Order in that state) -- which puts C back on.

What's the appropriate pattern for dealing with this?

Checking `isBeingPresented` doesn't work. These view controllers are in a custom `UIViewControllerContainer`, as well. That flag is read-only, but some knowledge about how it gets set would be great.

Comment: Can you show the scenario with corresponding codes?

Comment: What would be useful?

Comment: If the given `Order` has been changed in a pushed VC, then the condition for pushing it again in `viewDidAppear` would be false, wouldn't it?

Comment: I've added some examples to make this more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use ViewDidAppear for that. When you create your "next" view controller, create it and then call an view controller specific initialization method to handle what you have been handling in ViewDidAppear.

You want to decouple the view appearance from the Order state.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've considered this, though as I mentioned, there are other places (periodic asynchronous updates) that also call the setup. 

That's do-able - but I don't think it's appropriate for a presenting view controller to have to tell another view controller about its internals. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm. I'm thinking the best answer is to have an optional method in the protocol defined by the UIViewControllerContainer - willPresentChild or some such. Then, it's not the responsibility of the presenting VC, but of the parent, and automated and optional.